# Special Characters in flex from HTML Params

Tags: apache-flex, special-characters

I am accessing some params from HTML to flex, those are special characters(html codes).

Below is the Sample Code:

HTML Param:

```
flashvars.sampleText = "&#12473;&#12540;&#35895;&#12473;&#12540;&#35895;&#12473;&#12540;&#35895;&#12473;&#12540;&#35895;"
```

Flex Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>




    <s:Panel>   
<s:Label text="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.sampleText}" />
</s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

When i am checking the above sample code in IE Browser its working fine, But its not working in **Mozilla** and **Chrome** browsers.

What could be the Problem ? How can i able to display this in other browsers? Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in Advance

Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried url encoding your String in Javascript then decodinf in AS?

For e.g.:
**Javascript:**

```
flashvars.sampleText = escape("String with special characters");
```

**AS/MXML:**

```
<s:Label text="{unescape(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.sampleText)}" />
```

Hope it helps,
Rob

Comment: Its giving html codes what we have placed in html (like what we have placed in params that is coming directly).. But its not decoding

Comment: Instead of passing the encoded version try to pass the original character. Like this: flashvars.sampleText = escape("Á"); But with your characters.

Comment: But if am doing like without doing url endoing why its working with IE, why not with other browsers, any idea..